# Azure Runbooks - Import Commands From Separate Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, runbook

I have created Runbook A that has some declared variables and some functions.

```
// Runbook A
$myvar = "test"
Function MyFunc($var1) {
  Write-Output $var1
}

// Runbook B
Write-Output $myvar
MyFunc
```

How do I import the code from Runbook A into Runbook B so I can make the code in Runbook A reusable?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no direct way of doing what you ask for. You cant use runbooks as functions. But you could create your runbooks to be modular and invoke them.

You don't have to login to Azure to invoke a runbook. [Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) looks like a much better option.

Comment: Hello, how would I create a runbook to be modular? I'm not sure I want to use a webhook because I want to create reusable powershell functions shared across multiple runbooks.

Comment: well, you can't really do that. closest you can get - invoking runbooks from one another.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I created a powershell module .psm1 file.  It allows me to call the functions, but it's not letting me print the variables.  Still working on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1)

```
# Runbook_A
$global:FX = @'
$myvar = "test"
Function MyFunc($var1) {
  Write-Output $var1
}
'@
```

And in parent module:

```
# RunBook_B
.\Runbook_A.ps1
Invoke-Expression $global:FX

Write-Output $myvar
MyFunc "Hello $myvar"
```

Output:

```
test
Hello test
```

**Note:** Runbook_A should be published and located in the same Automation Account